# Chrome extension browserAction.onClicked not listening

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following in my background.js file which is referenced in manifest.json:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  console.log('browserAction clicked');
});
```

When I click on the browser action icon, I never see `browserAction clicked` printed to the console.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.log doesn't work in background.js. Use

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  alert('browserAction clicked');
});
```

instead of that.

To see the console messages that comes from the background.js

display the extension;

> chrome://extensions/.

- Make sure that developer mode is enabled
- Click on the "Inspect Views"
  of your background page
- You should see console messages under the
  console tab.

Answer (score 1):

Does the browser action have a popup? If so, the event won't fire.

Comment: That was one of the problems, yes.